# Best way to export Azure resource group configuration?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-resource-group

I've created a resource group on Azure containing all of my resources for my project that is coming to a close and I'd like to not be charged for the resources I will soon no longer be using. I'd like to come back to this project in the future however so my question is: is there a way of backing up my entire resource configuration so I can just redeploy it with ease in the future?

Many thanks.

Comment: There should be an ARM template that was responsible for deploying the resource group. Just copy that?

Answer (score 2):

- Yes, You Can Export Resources from ResourceGroup which will generate a new template and that exported template you can download and you can import the template later when you need.
- Select the resources from your resource group which you want to export and click on the export template.

[image]

- Once the Template is generated you can find an Option of download template as shown below.

[image]

- When you select custom deployment you can deploy the template which you downloaded.

[image]

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as an answer( click on the checkmark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to fill in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you